# How to pass mute option in video_tag with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, asset-pipeline, mute

I want to pass in an option to mute the video, while still using the rails asset pipeline. Can't find any documentation on this.

If anyone has any experience with this, or can point me to the rails source code it would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have tried:

```
<%= video_tag "home.mp4", :controls => false, :autobuffer => true, :autoplay => true, :loop => true, :id => "home-video" %>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please indent code using space so that it is properly formatted to improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

Although [rails document](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag) does not show *muted* attribute, but you can always add HTML (or custom) attributes by passing an attributes hash to options. Rails helper will simple add them. So in your case:

```
<%= video_tag "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4", controls: false, autoplay: true, muted: true, loop: true, id: "home-video"  %>
```

Btw, please note that *autobuffer* attribute is replaced by *[preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)*, and you don't need it because you have *autoplay*.